# How to make url string clickable in react-native-share

Tags: reactjs, react-native, hyperlink, react-native-ios

I have created the react native app and added Linking. It is working fine when i open the url in the browser testapp://params.
Now i want this link to be shared to other apps. So i used react-native-share library to share this. But this library just shows string as text but not clickable. How do i make this text as clickable so that when user clicks that link it will open my app.

```
 let shareOptions = {
  title: "React Native",
  message: "Hola mundo",
  url: "testapp://", //Here this should be clickable
  subject: "Share Link" //  for email
};
Share.open(shareOptions);
```

Can any one please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: apologies for the misunderstanding. To configure your app to be opened via a link is different depending on the platform.

## IOS

First add the following to your `Info.plist`

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>testapp</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

If editing in Xcode and not a text editor, create a key called "URL types", under `Item 0` create a key called `URL Schemes` and set `Item 0` under `URL Schemes` equal to a String `testapp` (or whatever the link should be)

Next in your `AppDelegate.m` file add this under your last import

```
#import <React/RCTLinkingManager.h>

Finally, add the following to your `AppDelegate.m` file under `@implementation AppDelegate`

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
  return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url
                      sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];
}
```

Now entering `testapp://` into an address bar will open your app

Unfortunately making this link clickable via iMessage will **not** work. Your best option instead is to host a simple webpage with the following script:

```
<script>
  window.location = "testapp://"
</script>
```

Then you could host it at `www.testapp.com` and it would open your app when the user navigates there.

## Android

Add an `intent-filter` to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
<intent-filter android:label="filter_react_native">
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:scheme="http" android:host="testapp" /> // A
</intent-filter>
```

That's it! Now `http://testapp` will open your app on android AND be clickable.

---

Comment: thanks for your reply. How do i add your code in the react-native-share library  let shareOptions = {
      title: "React Native",
      message: "Hola mundo",
      url: "testapp://",
      subject: "Share Link" //  for email
    };

Comment: I want to make the url to be clickable in react native share library

Comment: ah okay you want to setup external links to your app? I'll change my answer

Comment: I have modified the question to understand more clearly. Please check that thanks

Comment: okay I modified my answer to show configuration steps to setup external linking to your app

Comment: I already did that. Its opening when i type in the browser. My question here is now i want to share that testapp:// in whatsapp then that should be clickable which means users can simply click that testapp:// so that it will open my testapp.

Comment: for sharing i have used react-native-share library. In that library it is taking params like this  let shareOptions = {
  title: "React Native",
  message: "Hola mundo",
  url: "testapp://", //Here this should be clickable
  subject: "Share Link" //  for email
};
Share.open(shareOptions)

Comment: @Trinu I updated the android information to make it clickable, basically you have to set the scheme up to look like an http URL if you want external apps to recognize this is a clickable link. I'm not 100% sure on how to accomplish this on IOS but I will let you know if I found out

Comment: please read what I said carefully, I only provided an answer for android I do not know if this is possible on iOS without using universal links

Comment: Ok thanks robbie that is the only way left i will do that only.